# All Request redirect specific url

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, web

I serve my app in localhost:8084/ues/. I want to redirect all request from localhost:8084/ues/* to localhost:8084/ues/index.jsp. How can I to do this?

Comment: that means when giving first request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `web.xml` have the below code,

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/ues/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<servlet>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.myPackage.redirectServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


public class redirectServletextends HttpServlet{
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{

        try 
        {
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/index.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        } 
        catch(Exception e)
                {
                  //catch your exceptions
                }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a filter in Deployment Descriptor like

```
  <filter>
    <filter-name>Filter-Name</filter-name>
    <filter-class>Fully-Qualified-Class-Name</filter-class>
</filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Filter-Name</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>ues/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

and redirect to your desired Jsp from the `Filter`